# Magento 2 Send Order Emails Without Cron

Tags: magento2, cron, order-email, order-status, system-configuration

Due to some issue order emails are not sending with cron and always remain with pending status.

So I have to send it without cron. I have changed it to Send Asynchronously from Admin configuration. But still not getting emails.

Please help me.

Comment: you can use the https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app extension to send Mail